# How to add image in push notifications in flutter using fcm?

Tags: dart, flutter

i am using fcm for sending notifications and after receiving messages i am trying to display that message through local notification in mobile. but it is not allowing images to display. Any other solutions to display images

Comment: Can you please share what you are getting in a device as a push?

Comment: Share what you tried and which plugin you are using to display notification.

Comment: i am using local_notifications plugin. it is displaying image as icon only not like big picture style

Comment: but what if app is stoped

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin.

And take note of the notification behavior in Android. Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318614/why-is-my-smallicon-for-notifications-always-greyed-out/45318726#45318726).