# Flutter local notifications not showing icon on Android Oreo

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have made an app with notifications using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and it worked fine on Android Kitkat. However, on Android Oreo, it doesn't display the icon. It just displayed a colored grey box icon.

This is the line of code where I initialized the icon which will be used by the notification to display:

```
var initializationSettingsAndroid = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
```

I can confirm that I have all icons present for different densities in my drawable resources.

But I can't figure why it doesn't display on Android Oreo.

I would appreciate any form of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open [bug filed](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/730) for this behavior. As a workaround you can follow the solution [here](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/730#issuecomment-389545259).

> You need to:
>
> - Create an asset that only uses white pixels, on a transparent background. It's important to not use any colour other than white.
> - Your asset must be called `ic_notification.png`
> - Your assets must be placed inside `mipmap-*` directories and not `drawable-*` (as @wuppious mentioned).
>
> Your asset dimensions (in pixels):
> `mipmap-mdpi` - 24x24
> `mipmap-hdpi` - 36x36
> `mipmap-xhdpi` - 48x48
> `mipmap-xxhdpi` - 72x72
> `mipmap-xxxhdpi` - 96x96

Check also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45318726/8342742) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove background that icon, Android System receive only a transparent icon.

Check this for more info:
[remove bg](https://clevertap.com/blog/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending notifications manually, put icon name in the request as well.

e.g.

```
{
    "to" : "*****",
    "notification": {
        "icon": "ic_notification",
        "priority": "max",
        "body" : "Example Body Message",
        "title": "Example Title"
    }
}
```

credit: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/730#issuecomment-431786902