# Try displaying notification with xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ibeacon, proximity

I'm following this guide for implementing an app that uses proximity beacon:

https://github.com/Estimote/Xamarin-Bindings

I downloaded the ExampleApp folder from github and installed Estimote.Android.Proximity. It work fine.

But this is my problem:

```
//ExampleApps/Example.Android.Proximity/MainActivity.cs

class MyEnterHandler : Java.Lang.Object, Kotlin.Jvm.Functions.IFunction1
    {
        public Java.Lang.Object Invoke(Java.Lang.Object p0)
        {
            IProximityZoneContext context = (IProximityZoneContext)p0;

            Log.Debug("app", $"MyEnterHandler, context = {context}");

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Instead of Log.Debug I want to create my Notification.. How can I do it?

I tryed to create notification with this script:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            // Android 8.0 and up require a channel for the notifications
            var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Bluetooth activity", NotificationImportance.Low);
            var notificationManager = this.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .SetSmallIcon(global::Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo)
                .SetContentTitle("Proximity")
                .SetContentText("Proximity demo is scanning for beacons")
                .Build();
```

But I have the problem with this.getSystemService (I haven't Context in "MyEnterHandler class")

Comment: You can pass the context in the MyEnterHandler class Constructor while creating the object.

Comment: @Jaymin how can do it?

Comment: is this code in the MainActivity ?

Comment: @Jaymin yes. MyEnterHandler is another class in the MainActivity

Comment: Cast `context` to MainActivity and try

Comment: Check my answer with full sample code for android here 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57248893/xamarin-forms-push-notification-is-not-working-on-android-7-1-2/57271782#57271782

Comment: @Pompeo94, The  Context is the type of **Android.Content.Context**, please take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - create Notification channel

```
void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                return;
            }

        var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name), NotificationImportance.Default)
        {
            Description = ""
        };

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

> - use notificationManager to send notification

```
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                                      .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.outline_message_24)
                                      .SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name))
                                      .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                      .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                      .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
```