# Xamarin Forms Android Push Notifications not received when app has been swiped closed

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

I have had push notifications configured in my Xamarin Forms app for the last year and this week decided to update to the new SDK, on iOS this was smooth sailing but on Android I am having problems.

I have tried to copy the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm and believe I am 90% of the way there as my app will happily receive push notifications when it is in the foreground and background, but my app cannot receive push notifications when it has been swiped closed (not force shut). I know this is 100% not a device issue as I tested the old configuration using the FirebaseService class and it works fine. I am also using 'Data' notifications.

I was able to find the following error message in the device log when a push notification is sent **"Error (6621) / AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.notificationhubs.NotificationListener.onPushNotificationReceived(android.content.Context, com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.notificationhubs.NotificationMessage)' on a null object reference"**

Please see the code for my MainActivity class below.

```
[Activity(Label = "AndroidNotificationTest", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Listen for push notifications
            NotificationHub.SetListener(new AzureListener());

            // Start the SDK
            NotificationHub.Start(this.Application, Constants.NotificationHubName, Constants.ListenConnectionString);
            NotificationHub.AddTag("Developer");

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            CreateNotificationChannel();
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
                return;

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
            {
                Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
            };

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    internal class AzureListener : Java.Lang.Object, INotificationListener
    {
        public void OnPushNotificationReceived(Context context, INotificationMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message received with title {message.Title} and body {message.Body}");
        }
    }
```

And my Android Manifest File.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.package.appname">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <application android:label="AndroidNotificationTest.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

I have spent days on this but I am stumped at this stage on what the problem is.

Comment: You could post the issue to https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-xamarin/issues .

Comment: I have posted the issue there, thanks Lucas.

Comment: Try to make OnPushNotificationReceived asynchronous. async void OnPushNotificationReceived

Comment: Hello Melissa, have you any update on the issue? As I have your very same problem, in the I filed an issue on the GitHub Xamarin.Components repo, here https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/1255 with a reference to your original issue.

Comment: Found it! Once the app is deployed in release mode, the notifications are ok even with the app swiped out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my working code helps you.

I wrote this code before the new documentation with AzureListener class but it's still valid.

[Xamarin forms: Push notification is not working on Android 7.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57248893/xamarin-forms-push-notification-is-not-working-on-android-7-1-2/57271782#57271782)

```
        //if i want more than one notification ,different unique value in every call
    Random u = new Random ();

    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O) {

        string channelName = Resources.GetString (Resource.String.channel_name);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;



             notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder (this, channelName)
                    .SetContentTitle (title)
                    .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_g)
                    .SetContentText (messageBody)
                    .SetAutoCancel (true)
                    .SetContentIntent (pendingIntent);


        var notificationManager = GetSystemService (Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;


        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel (channelName, "notification channel", NotificationImportance.Default);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel (channel);

        notificationManager.Notify (u.Next(), notificationBuilder.Build ());


    } 
    else
    {

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;


             notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder (this)
                .SetContentTitle (title)
                .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_g)
                .SetContentText (messageBody)
                .SetAutoCancel (true)
                .SetContentIntent (pendingIntent);


        var notificationManager = GetSystemService (Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        notificationManager.Notify (u.Next(), notificationBuilder.Build ());
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mich, no luck with this code unfortunately. Judging by the error message I am getting I don't think it is the code within in OnPushNotificationReceived method that is the problem and more so trying to invoke the actual method itself. I also tried to make the method async as per your comment above but had no luck with that either.

Are you using the Azure Listener class now in your code?

Comment: Hi, from your question i saw the changes again on notification hub. The documentation sends me here https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet/tree/main/Samples/Xamarin/GetStartedXamarinAndroid ...... also this code doesn't have the Azure Listener

Comment: Sorry, i don't have updated sample with this functionality.

Comment: Yeah I previously had my code like this with the FirebaseService and it worked perfect, but thought I would update my code to match the new documentation that I linked in the original question. I think I will have to revert back until the team can provide a working sample as I have asked on many different platforms and from the support team can give me an answer.

Comment: Please if you find the solution post it here !