# React native show ICON only not full image

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, notifications

I am trying to implement the notification which working fine only facing one issue that when I want to show icon only with data it will show as an image.

The Library I am using is [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)

For example, I want to show like this but it shows large image too on click of an arrow button.

[image]
[image]

Right now it is like this

[image]

That is how I want.

[image]

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                    android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification"/>  
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@android:color/white"/>
```

While on server side

> $notification = array('content-available' => true, 'mutable-content' => true, 'title' => $title, 'text' => $body, 'icon' => $icon, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');

If I pass icon then nothing will show if I use image then icon show but with the big image too.

My code is as below

```
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import { PushNotificationIOS } from "react-native";
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from "react-navigation";
import {ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';
const localNotification = data => {
  console.log("const localNotification" + JSON.stringify(data));
  if (data) PushNotification.localNotification(data);
  return null;
};
let getToken;

const setToken = token => (getToken = token.token);

const configure = () => {
  PushNotification.configure({
    onRegister: setToken,
    // largeIcon: "https://stag2.com/uploads/qr/407xg1.png",
    // smallIcon: "ic_notification",
    // ongoing: true,
    onNotification(notification) {
      onNotification(notification);
    }, 
    senderID: "5545454654654654",
  //  SmallIcon:"ic_notification",
    permissions: {
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true
    },

    popInitialNotification: true,
    requestPermissions: true
  });
};
let onNotification = (notification) => {
  notification.android.setSmallIcon('ic_notification')
  // if (!!notification.title && !!notification.body) {
    // PushNotification.localNotification({
    //   title: notification.title,
    //   message:"urfusion",
    // });
  // }
};
export { configure, localNotification, getToken };
```

I got what I wanted if I push local notification which called when the app opens on notification click event but I want on remote push notification not on local one.

```
let onNotification = (notification) => {
  notification.android.setSmallIcon('ic_notification')
  // if (!!notification.title && !!notification.body) {
     PushNotification.localNotification({
       title: notification.title,
       message:"urfusion",
     });
   }
};
```

Comment: have you found solution to your problem? I'm experiencing the same issue and I can't find the solution

Comment: no, I have released in the same way at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Icons need to be with a transparent background. you can read more here : 
[read more](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1796)

On the other hand, for notification, you need to use different icons for different versions of android. you can read more here : 
[read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318614/why-is-my-smallicon-for-notifications-always-greyed-out/45318726#45318726)

Comment: I have already added the icon property in my `AndroidManifest.xml`