# RNFirebase Notification Issue Displaying Icons

Tags: android, react-native

I am using RNFirebase notification package ref. https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/messaging/introduction

i have follow all the steps mentioned in the documentation, RNfirebase handle the incomming notification by itself so need to implement extra module rf. https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/introduction this only help when app is foreground

**issue**

[image: notification icon on tray]

as shown in above image the icon is perfectly visible when notification come form cloud. but when i open the notification tray

[image: notification when tray is open]

you can clearly see that icon is gray out (i have searched the issue and removed the alpha channel  from the icon ) still the issue is same.

ref 1. https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/730
ref 2. [Why is my smallIcon for Notifications always greyed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318614/why-is-my-smallicon-for-notifications-always-greyed-out)
ref 3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply Android an icon that qualify the Notification icon standard see [Material guideline](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-notifications.html#anatomy-of-a-notification).

> 1. The app icon:
>      The app icon is a small two-dimensional representation of your app's identity. It appears in monochrome in the status bar. If your app sends a wide variety of notifications, you may replace your app's identity icon with a symbol that reflects the content type. For example, Google Now uses a cloud icon for weather notifications.

summary - you need an icon with transparent background - inside the icon as well.

In your case you seem to have a white background inside your icon Android system converts all color to a single color by contrast

- dark or white -

In your icon all converted to gray.
you can set your default icon and color in `AndroidManifest`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/dustyOrange" />
```