# Smartech SDK notification icon looking as square block

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, sdk, icons

I am using Netcore Smartech Android SDK version 2.2.19. I have added the meta-data tag for the notification icon as per their [documentation](https://docs.netcoresmartech.com/docs/android-sdk-v2-push-notification#custom-push-notification-icon) but I am not able to see the icon. Gray square comes in the place of the notification icon.

```
<meta-data  
    android:name="SMT_SMALL_NOTIFICATION_ICON"  
    android:value="@drawable/ic_notif"/>

<!-- I also tried below syntax. -->
<meta-data  
    android:name="SMT_SMALL_NOTIFICATION_ICON"  
    android:value="ic_notif.png"/>
```

Comment: Seems your image lacks transparency. Get it checked

Comment: The icon is transparent. We are following material design guidelines for the notification icon.

Comment: check out this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45318726/7209822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing only the icon name as they specified <small_notification_icon_name>. Your code should look like this.

```
<meta-data  
    android:name="SMT_SMALL_NOTIFICATION_ICON"  
    android:value="ic_notif"/>
```

Also, make sure your icon sizes match with the valid sizes for the notification icon. You can refer to this [document](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons).