# Notification icon is greyed out sometimes but works sometime

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, android-icons

I am working on an Android application in which I face an issue in Android push notification icon.

The notification icon does not display its content instead displaying in grey colour.

After the research, I could understand that there is a change required in icon for adding transparent and/or white backgrounds since the Android version 5.0

But, my problem now is that I am unable to strongly convey my client about this issue as he shared a screenshot of his **Realme X2 Pro** device.

[image]

It seems that sometimes the device displays in right manner but sometimes not. Please help me find out the solution.

Comment: It probably have to do something with icon itself . have you tried using the recommended  icon specification ? [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318614/why-is-my-smallicon-for-notifications-always-greyed-out) if you haven't already. The icon you are using is not as per android specification as it says it has to have transparent background .

Comment: The query of my client is if the problem is with icon, how does it work sometimes

Comment: Pls keep the client out of this site. I simply asked you to debug the issue . It maybe a bug in that device's firmware since they mostly use Custom Os . Just try the recommended way and see if works or not .

Comment: Sure. Let me try and post it here on how does it work

Comment: @RakeshL you got any solutions?

Comment: @sasikumar, Yes, Please look at the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45318726/2409495 . Hope it may help you.