# Notification icon on Android shown as a white square

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging with my Flutter app.

I am sending Push Notifications to my app using the Firebase Console.

My issue is regarding the notification icon on Android.

I have created an icon with Android Asset Studio, as follows:

[image]

Then I have included the downloaded assets into their respective folder at android/app/main/res/mipmap.

On Manifest I have included the needed meta-data code:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@mipmap/ic_stat_logopush" />
```

But when sending a notification, a white square is shown.

[image]

[image]

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Edit:

This my current file:

[image]

Comment: Does this happen on every device or some devices?

Comment: Try putting them in `drawable` directories, not `mimpap` directories. AFAIK, `mimpap` is only for launcher icons.

Comment: @CommonsWare, let me try your proposal

Comment: Is the background actually transparent? Android will only use the outlines of your icon.

Comment: Your image doesn't seems to be completely transparent , you need to make background transparent.

Comment: @NitishChaudhary, I have created the image with a transparent background. How can I be sure that it is really transparent?

Comment: What's the dimension of the image you are using , above attach image has a dimension of 512x512 which too large for notification. Can you reduce it to 24x24 , 36x36 and 48x48 for hdpi , xhdp and xxhdpi.

Comment: To check transparency you can use online editor - https://www.photopea.com/

Comment: @NitishChaudhary, it is transparent now, but the issue is there. I have downloaded the assets from Android Asset Studio with their end size depending on their respective drawable folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you generated the icons of wrong size.
I re-generated them using the android asset studio and seems to be working at my end.
You can download then using this link:

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=text&source.text.text=capenergy&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_capenergy

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I have downloaded your proposed link from Android Asset Studio, copied the respective drawable folders to res, and changed the AndroidManifest file including: <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_capenergy" />

Comment: But the same result with the notification icon

Comment: Is your meta-data tag inside you application class tag?

Comment: Use this link to confirm if image source has been added to correct places. [link](https://medium.com/nonstopio/change-the-firebase-notification-icon-in-a-flutter-245b7f7dc546)

Comment: Yes, I have followed exactly the given tutorial

Comment: i know you are in the right way. I will try later from the beginning.Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 4):

Background of notification icon should be transparent
From Android 5.0 Lollipop Notification icons must be entirely white.

Comment: not necessary "must"... Android will exchange every not-fully-transparent pixel into solid white (or dk gray, depends on background color of status bar), only transparent ones will stay transparent

Answer (score 2):

I think you should checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45318726/5519300). I also had a lot of problems with this so I saved that answer to my bookmarks ;)

Comment: Thank you @Tarik, I think my icon is ok for that use. But may be not. I will add it to my question to be sure.

Comment: @TarikHuber: if the entire answer is in that link, please mark the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in the `main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="{replace with your package name}.default_notification_icon"
           android:resource="@mipmap/launcher_icon" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
           android:resource="@mipmap/launcher_icon" />
```

And run

```
flutter clean
```

invalid cache and restart and then

```
flutter pub get
```

It should now work

NB: Don't just copy/paste, take time to replace {package name} with your actual package name. ;)

Comment: How to do suggest to replace {package name} when you're using app flavors?