# how to change icon on Android notification tray using flutter local notification?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-local-notification

I am using [flutter local notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to show notification on my app locally (not FCM).

I can show the icon of my app on the status bar like this on my Android app

[image]

but when I open the Android notification tray, the icon is just white, it doesn't show my icon like this

[image]

so how to change icon on Android notification tray using flutter local notification?

currently I am using `flutter_local_notifications: ^9.6.1`

Comment: for the white icon  and gray showing is that the image needs to be transparent background https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_example 
you can test your icon here also since they have same output when using notification

also take a look for this also since it the same as you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318614/why-is-my-smallicon-for-notifications-always-greyed-out/45318726#45318726

Comment: @ArbiterChil yup, thats the solution

Answer (score 0):

sometimes its problem with the icon. you need to replace it with some other icon and try. there is site you can use for icon generating and testing the image type.
[LINK](https://jgilfelt.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=notification_icon)