# Flutter firebase messaging: Cannot solve problem with white Square instead of icon for push notifications

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created the icons here:

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=lightbulb_outline&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_lightbulb_outline

added the png-files to the *android/app/src/main/res* drawable folders and renamed the icons to notification_icon.png.

and added

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"                     android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" /> <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"                     android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />`

to the AndroidManifest.

But I still get the white square (Simulator and Device) instead of the icon.

The ***minSdkVersion is 19*** (21 also does not work) and the ***targetSdkVersion is 33***

Does anyone has an idea what could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: I think this answer may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45318726

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I defined the

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"                     android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" /> <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"                     android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

inside the activity-tag and not inside the application-tag